# Prevalence of 'well-rounded' beach fabric on the Foreshore

Tags: rocks, data-analysis, erosion, coastal

Apologies for the vagueness of this query, but generally, would it be plausible to state that the prevalence of 'sub-rounded'* beach fabric is more common at the foreshore than 'sub-angular'* beach fabric? This is in the context of a completely hypothetical scenario.

(These descriptions denoted by '*' are referenced the Power's Angularity Index of Smoothness)

Comment: is this what you are asking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundness_(geology)  ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Sorry for not explicitly mentioning it above..